How to prove that the product of two numbers, each of them being a sum of four perfect squares, is also a sum of four perfect squares?
This is problem # 165 from my beloved handbook of ancient math problems written by Chistyakov.
One must prove that if we have two sums and each of these two sums represents a sum of four perfect squares (the author did NOT specify they all must be different from each other) then the product of those two sums will also be a sum of four perfect squares.
E.g., we have natural numbers m and n.
\begin{align} m &= a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2; \\ n &= e^2 + f^2 + g^2 + h^2, \end{align}
where $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h \in \Bbb N$ or possibly $\Bbb N ^\ast$.
We need to confirm that the product mn can always be decomposed into four addends, each of which is a perfect square as well. Thus, $mn = p^2 + q^2 + r^2 + s^2$.
This is indeed one of the hardest problems from my book!
I tried solving it by brute force. Tried to calculate my product in terms of $a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h$. We have $mn = (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2) \times (e^2 + f^2 + g^2 + h^2)$. If we open the parentheses according to the distributive law of multiplication, we will get sixteen addends $(4 \times 4 = 16)$. Here I am stuck because I do not understand if this step may be helpful. Maybe it isn’t. (I am thinking of regrouping our 16 addends after parentheses’ opening, but why do I need to do that?) Besides this, I have no other ideas. Oh, and the author does not provide the answer! No solution at all and the end of the book.
So you see I really need some help. Sorry for my mediocre grammar, please.

See Euler's 4-square identity

Also Lagrange's four square theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_four-square_theorem

In the previous reference see the interpretation in terms of norms of quaternions.

Quaternions would do it. Might be able to do it with complex numbers.
